# Laravel random to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

What i'm try to do: Then user registered on my website he's got a email with confirmation random code.

My controller looks like that:

```
$activation_code = str_random(40);
        /*
         * Register user.
         */
        $user = Sentry::register([
            'username'      => Input::get('username'),
            'email'         => Input::get('email'),
            'password'      => Input::get('password'),
            'language_id'   => $language->id,
            'activation_code' => $activation_code
        ]);
        $user->slug = Str::slug($user->username);
        $user->save();
```

But then i check databse, the activation_code cell is empty. What i'm doing wrong? Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant the  activation column not table, check your fillable array and make sure its in there.

EDIT
Scratch that, it looks like like your auto activating the user, no activation code necessary in that case.

Comment: is it saving the user just not the activation_code for the use? if you dd the user returned from register does it have the code?

Comment: I may be reading the docs wrong but it looks like the user should be created first, the registered with sentry. https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#sentry::register()

Answer (score 0):

FIXED! Works fine with:

```
 $activationCode = $user->getActivationCode();
```